# Why does this node.js http request hang indefinitely?

Tags: node.js, ssl, http-headers

I'm trying to grab an HTTP response header with the following code:

```
var http = require('http');

const options = {
    hostname: 'google.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
  };

  const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log('No more data in response.');
    });
  });

  req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
  });
```

However, this code just hangs indefinitely in node with no output or exit. Why is this? I adapted this from the official documentation here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you've missed a call to `req.end()` at the end even though the [documentation you've cited](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) clearly states

> With http.request() one must **always call req.end()** to signify the end of the request - even if there is no data being written to the request body.

Then, port 443 is for HTTPS and not for plain HTTP. This means you have to use the `https` interface instead of `http`:

```
var https = require('https');
...
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
```